# Upload image and associate it with row on database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to do this with cakephp.

I will have a form that will allow the user to type in a school name, school phone number, and also upload a pre determined sized image as a thumbnail for that school. Then when that form is submitted, on the webpage I want it to display that thumbnail with the associated school.

1. How do I accomplish uploading a image through cakephp, and somehow associated that in my mySQL database?
2. Adding onto question #1, how would I display that image in a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to link an image to your database, you can also use the following method:

- Create an "img" column in your table
- When uploading your image to the server (you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673408/simple-tutorial-for-file-uploads-in-cakephp-2-0 for that) save your pathname in a variable
- Save this variable (example "http://www.domain.com/gallery/image1.jpg") in the "img" column in your table

Then when displaying the image in your view, just use this value from the database:

```
<img src="<?php echo $data.img ?>" />
```

(above code example is not with cakephp)

Answer (score 1):

There is a great plugin for handling image uploads which will do all this for you.

https://github.com/josegonzalez/upload

It will also associate the upload with a Model, either on the model or joined.

To display images in the view, you should use the Html helper.

`$this->Html->image('../files/<Model>/<field>);`